# Como colocar mais informações na janela ao clicar num Marker?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, marker

Ao abrir o mapa, na MainActivity, exibo alguns pinos na tela(markerOptions), conforme códigos abaixo:

```
WAPIService.getInstance().getPontosMapeamento(latitude, longitude, new FutureCallback<List<MapPins>>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(List<MapPins> result) {
                        for (MapeamentoColaborativo mapPin : result){
                            showMapPins(mapPin.getLat_Pino(),mapPin.getLng_Pino(),mapPin.getPino(),mapPin.getAddress());//getAddress no formato para exibicao
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "Ocorreu algum problema", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

showMapPins:

```
...
protected GoogleMap map;
...
private void showMapPins(double lat, double lng, String pin, String address) {
    LatLng location = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(location);
    switch (pin) {
        case "1":
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Marker1").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mk_one)));//TODO exibir endereço
            break;
        case "2":
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Marker2").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mk_two)));
            break;
        case "3":
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Marker3").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mk_three)));
            break;
        case "4":
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Marker4").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mk_four)));
            break;
        case "5":
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Marker5").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mk_five)));
            break;
        case "6":
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Marker6").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mk_six)));
            break;
    }
}
```

Como posso colocar este endereço como um "sub-titulo" para aparecer ao se clicar no marcador no mapa? .title("Marker1\n"+address) ->  não funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o que pretende é apenas adicionar uma string por debaixo do título da Marker use [MarkerOptions#snippet(String snippet)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions#snippet(java.lang.String)).

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location)
                                 .title("MarkerX")
                                 .snippet(address)
                                 .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mk_six)));
```

É no entanto possível personalizar completamente o conteúdo da janela de informações do Marker.
Para isso, é necessário criar uma implementação completa da interface [InfoWindowAdapter](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter) e chamar `map.setInfoWindowAdapter()` com a sua implementação.
Para mais informações veja [Janelas de informações](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows), na documentação.